# Capybara - how to test presence of class attribute for nth element

Tags: capybara

I have a list like this

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li .current></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

and if a user clicks on an li it adopts the class "current". I want to test this in capybara but im wondering how to write the test. I want to be specific in the test by saying the second element should only have the class "current".

i know how to target the second element using xpath i.e //li[2] and i also know how target an element by class //li[@class="current"] but i dont know how to bring them both together to to write this test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want? :)

```
assert _the_li_element_you_found.node[:class] == "current"
```

Comment: i tried that but it didnt work so instead i tried assert _the_li_element_you_found[:class] == "current" which did work. Thanks for your help. Got me there in the end.